# How to configure centos server on LAN connection

Tags: centos, local-area-network

I am having an issue accessing my server outside via the web. I have a test server with esxi installed, and a centos vm configured with a local LAN IP address 192.168.0.199 and from the console I can ping google fine.

My ifconfig is setup like this

```
DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED=Yes
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
TYPE="Ethernet"
HWADDR=00:0c:29:fd:bb:c9
IPADDR=192.168.0.199
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

ifconfig shows this

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:FD:BB:C9  
      inet addr:192.168.0.199  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2601:1c0:8602:1b54:20c:29ff:fefd:bbc9/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fefd:bbc9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:24917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9325311 (8.8 MiB)  TX bytes:1143624 (1.0 MiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:649938 (634.7 KiB)  TX bytes:649938 (634.7 KiB)`
```

Which looks correct to me.

I am not sure what else to look for or change on my local router or on the server.

Comment: I did add that ip to DMZ so no ports should be blocked on my local router.

Comment: You seem to use NetworkManager, try to `nmtui` or `nmcli`.

Comment: both commands not found

Comment: Oh,,, Quickly add `ip route add table special default via _your_default_gateway_`. And confirmed put the end of ifcfg-eth0 `GATEWAY=_your_default_gateway_`

Comment: Even after adding gateway, I can still not access the server via web browser. I can ping the ip, and even when I ping a website that is hosted on the server I get the correct IP address.

Comment: It was a firewall issue in iptables (resolved)